# Вывод данных групированые по имени

Tags: php, mysql

Нужна ваша помощь

есть данные

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`id` int, `Bid` int, `Cid` int, `value` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id`, `Bid`, `Cid`, `value`)
VALUES
    (4, 22, 11, 33),
    (5, 24, 11, 33),
    (6, 25, 11, 33),
    (7, 24, 11, 100),
    (8, 25, 16, 150)
;
```

Хочу вывести в один ряд все данные например. 
Результат:

```
  cid **11**  33 33 33 100

      **16**  150
```

как можно реализовать такое в php + mysql ?

Comment: select cid, group_concat(`value`) from Table1 group by cid

Comment: splash56 идиально но вопрос а в таблицу как закинуть? так как они идут через запятую

Comment: explode(','  тут значение)